# Python: How to prevent questions with negative answers being randomly generated

Tags: python

My task is to create a maths quiz for primary school children. this is what I have done so far:

```
import random
import math

def test():
    num1=random.randint(1, 10)
    num2=random.randint(1, 10)

    ops = ['+', '-', '*']
    operation = random.choice(ops)

    num3=int(eval(str(num1) + operation + str(num2)))

    print ("What is {} {} {}?".format(num1, operation, num2))
    userAnswer= int(input("Your answer:"))
    if userAnswer != num3:
        print ("Incorrect. The right answer is {}".format(num3))
        return False
    else:
        print ("correct")
        return True

username=input("What is your name?")
print ("Welcome "+username+" to the Arithmetic quiz")

correctAnswers=0
for question_number in range(10):
    if test():
        correctAnswers +=1

print("{}: You got {} answers correct".format(username, correctAnswers))
```

What I now need to do is make my program only create questions with positive answers. e.g nothing like `3-10=-7`

I've tried searching everywhere online but I cant find anything so I've turned to you guys for help. Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: you just need a if statement after the `num3=int(eval(str(num1) + operation + str(num2)))` which says `if num>0:` and indent all the lower regions into that if statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose the numbers such that `num2` will be between `1` and `num1` like:

```
num1=random.randint(1, 10)
num2=random.randint(1, num1)
```

or that `num1 > num2`:

```
n1=random.randint(1, 10)
n2=random.randint(1, 10)
num1 = max(n1,n2)
num2 = min(n1,n2)
```

i would go with the first option. no extra variables, no extra lines.

Comment: Thanks! You seem to know your stuff. Last thing. I would really appreciated it if you looked over my code and saw if anything can be shortened. This is large a piece of my coursework and one of the specification is to make the code short as possible.

Comment: for that i would require for a money transfer ;) nevertheless, 
no need for `else`  after a `return` statement. and in python you should use `pep8` Style Guide. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: What should I replace the else with?

Comment: no need for it.
just remove the indentation from the rest of the code after the `if` and `return`

Answer (score 2):

What I would recommend is:

```
#Random code...

if num1<num2:
    num1, num2 = num2, num1

#Rest of program
```

So that 3 - 7 = -4 becomes 7 - 3 = 4

The reason I recommend doing this is that the answer would still be the same as the previous equation, just positive instead of negative, so you are still testing the same numbers.

Comment: Python has a nice way of swapping that doesn't require explicit use of a temporary variable, the above can be written as `if num1 < num2: num1, num2 = num2, num1`

Comment: @JonClements Yeah thanks for reminding me of that. I was looking over some Java questions and the easiest way to do it in java is with a temporary variable, so I had a java mindset coming into this question.

Answer (score 1):

Keep the larger number on the left of the expression, also use operator instead of eval:

```
from operator import add, sub, mul

def test():
    num1 = random.randint(1, 10)
    num2 = random.randint(1, 10)
    d = {"+": add, "-": sub, "*": mul}
    operation = random.choice(list(d)))
    num1 = max(num1, num2)
    num2 = min(num1, num2)
    num3 = d[operation](num1, num2)
    print("What is {} {} {}?".format(num1, operation, num2))
    userAnswer = int(input("Your answer:"))
    if userAnswer != num3:
        print("Incorrect. The right answer is {}".format(num3))
        return False
    else:
        print("correct")
        return True

username = input("What is your name?")
print("Welcome {} to the Arithmetic quiz".format(username))
correctAnswers = sum(test() for question_number in range(10))
print("{}: You got {} answers correct".format(username, correctAnswers))
```

Or as @jonclements suggests sorting will also work:

```
num2, num1 = sorted([num1, num2])
```

On another note you should really be using a try/except to verify the user input and cast to an int otherwise the first value that cannot be cast to an int your program will crash.

Comment: It doesn't matter in this case, but one could also consider `num2, num1 = sorted([num1, num2])` instead of the `min`/`max` - good use of `operator` though :)

Comment: would do:  `random.choice(d.keys())` instead of declare them twice.

Comment: @Udy, True but would have to call list on d.keys in python 3

Comment: @padric, True, however i would declare `list` and not writing the `ops` twice :D

Comment: @Udy, changed just for you ;)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham if you're going to do that - just use `list(d)` - then you don't have to worry about 2.x and 3.x.

Comment: @JonClements, yep, you got up early this morning ;)

Answer (score 0):

after the code that chooses the random numbers you can add this while loop:

```
while num3<0:
    num1=random.randint(1, 10)
    num2=random.randint(1, 10)

    ops = ['+','-','*']
    operation = random.choice(ops)
    num3=int(eval(str(num1) + operation + str(num2)))
```

It will enter this loop every time the answer is negative. This will ensure that the answer is positive when the program quits the loop.

Answer (score 0):

A change in one line should do it:

`if num1 > num2:
    num3=int(eval(str(num1) + operation + str(num2)))
else:
    num3=int(eval(str(num2) + operation + str(num1)))`